# How to upload multiple files with additional info inside object

Tags: javascript, file-upload, axios, form-data

I'm trying to upload multiple files using `FormData` as an array of objects that contain file and other necessary properties, but I'm not getting expected results.

```
import api from './api';

const formData = new FormData();

// File input with multiple attribute
const files = this.$refs.photo.files;

if (files.length > 0) {
  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    formData.append('files', { file: files[i], someOtherProp: 'value' });
  }
}

api.createArticle(formData);
```

```
// api/index.js

import axios from 'axios';
import config from '@/config';

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: config.api,
  timeout: config.apiTimeout,
});

createArticle(payload) {
  return api.post('/articles', payload, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    }
  });
}

export {
  createArticle
};
```

When I send request this is what I get

[image]

Comment: You're not supposed to append objects, just strings or files. Append the files and additional info separately. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append

Comment: @ADyson server sees files as array when I send just file without other props using `files` syntax. - `formData.append('files', files[i]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation of the FormData append function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) shows that it accepts either two or three parameters (the 3rd being optional).

Of the second parameter - `value` - it says:

> The field's value. This can be a USVString or Blob (including
> subclasses such as File). If none of these are specified the value is
> converted to a string.

Your code tries to pass an object for this parameter, rather than a string or Blob. Therefore FormData is doing exactly what the documentation says it will do that in that situation, and converting that object to a string. `[Object object]` is what JavaScript always outputs by default if you try to stringify an object directly.

If you wish to append a name for the file specifically, as you can see from the documentation the optional 3rd parameter `filename` is provided specifically for that purpose.

However if you want to pass some other related property, then you'll need to do that in a separate field in the FormData.

Also you should not append data items with the same name repeatedly - your server may only see the last one. For that to work the most reliable way you should use array syntax e.g. `formData.append("files[]"...`, so then the server should see an array of data with that name, rather than a single item. You could do the same for these additional properties you want to pass, then you can also pass multiple items and their index number will match with the index number of the file they're related to, when your server receives the POSTed data.

For example, something like this should work better:

```
for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  formData.append('files[]', files[i]);
  formData.append('someOtherProp[]', 'value');
}
```

Comment: I know that I can send other prop as separated prop, but that's not what I'm going to achieve. For example, if I upload multiple images, I want to select some of that images and say that image is main.

Comment: Well you need to figure out some way of representing that fact to the server, but you _must_ do it via a separate property - e.g. perhaps you can `.append("mainImage", "filenameOfMainImage")` or `.append("mainImageIndex", 0)` or something - just some info to tell the server which of the images in the array is the "main" one. Use your imagination.

Comment: However, I've answered the specific question of why you get the output you saw - it's because what you provided to the `.append()` method isn't supported. You _must_ provide only either a string or a Blob for the `value` property. I've also explained a possible alternative approach which _is_ supported, and given you ideas for other alternative approaches as well, for your specific use case. So I think the question is more than solved. The exact data structure you decide upon is really up to you, but I have explained what you are and are not allowed to do.

Comment: Thanks, I will go with sending files separated form other props.